# OCaml: Can't figure out the error in this snippet

Tags: ocaml

I am working on an OCaml assignment and am a bit stuck. Currently this is what I have:

```
let rec icent (image) =
 match image with
 | [] -> 0.0
 | imgHead::imgTail -> (centImCol(image, 1)) +. (icent(imgHead))
;;

let rec jcent (image) =
 match image with
 | [] -> 0.0
 | imgHead::imgTail -> (centImRow(imgHead, 1)) +. (jcent(imgTail))
;;
```

where the `centIm*` functions are properly defined. The required signature for this is `int list list -> float`. Currently, I am only achieving error after error and can't quite get a grasp on why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
let rec centImRow(image, start_j) =
  match image with
    | imgHead::imgTail -> (sumRowCount(imgHead, start_j)) + (centImRow(imgTail, start_j+1))
    | _ -> 0
    ;;

let rec centImCol(image, start_i) =
  match image with
    | imgHead::imgTail -> (sumRowCount(imgHead, start_i)) + (centImCol(imgTail, start_i+1))
    | _ -> 0
    ;;
```

Comment: Could you give us the type signatures of `centImCol` and `centImRow`?

Comment: I added the centImCol and centImRow

Comment: Don't use parenthesis for functions definitions or calls. So code `let rec  centImCol image starti =` ... and call `centImCol imgtail (starti+1)`

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is that your recursive call to `icent` is applied to the head of the list. But the head of a list is not a list. But `icent` is supposed to work for lists.

The recursive call of a list handling function is going to be applied to the tail of the list.

I'd also expect *some* function to be applied to the head of the list. Otherwise nothing is going on other than the recursion itself.